# Faded gauge colours in flexdashboard

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have created some gauges in a `flexdashboard` and am using the default "success", "warning" and "danger" colours. However, the gauges show a nice full colouration in the scripting shell but are faded when knitted to an HTML dashboard.

Code and issue shown below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think most of that is done with CSS. Have you looked into [Style your apps with CSS](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html)?

Comment: maybe show code?

Comment: Anything? This seems very odd to me.

Answer (score 2):

Although you did not include the YAML header, it is very likely that this problem is due to the `theme` you selected. When I specify NO theme:

```
---
title: "My Flexdashboard with Gauges"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: fill
---
```

I get a vibrant green color (my success levels are set from 0 to 100 here):

[image]

However when I specify the `united` theme:

```
---
title: "My Flexdashboard with Gauges"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: fill
    theme: united
---
```

I get washed out colors:

[image]

You can also force the colors to be darker by setting color manually:

```
gauge(50, 0, 100, symbol='%', 
      gaugeSectors(success=c(0, 100), color=c("#1a7b1a"))
)
```

Comment: I have the same problem, currently in Flexdashboard with Shiny I am using the "Cerulean" theme, but I modified the original theme in the package folder. In .css I change colors and other things, for example the Value Boxes have the perfect color, but I can't find the element to define the colors of the gauges and they appear with a low opacity, for the value boxes in .css is defined:

`.value-box-success, .bg-success {background-color: #73a839;}`